# sed: replace all non-alpha numeric characters except ">"

Tags: sed

I would like to replace all non- alphanumeric characters in lines that start with ">" but NOT replace the ">".

eg.

```
>header 44554%782 & -GB
```

would become

```
>header44554782GB
```

Also would like to know more generally, how to specify multiple "protected" non-alpha/num characters, for example, if I wanted to keep ">" and spaces or spaces and underscores.

This gets me halfway there (removes all non-alpha numeric).

```
sed '/^>/s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g'
```

Any ideas?

*update*

I did not provide enough information on my datastructure.

An example of the text file I need to process is here:

```
>gi-565662%% 2s-0[protein]
MPPACTYUSYUUSUSUSUSUUSU
SKKKYTYSSALLATLLAY
>gi|47234377324|+98923[protein]
ATTYTYTFYATYFTTTFARRRLAVVVATPATYTKKKK
>gi|23432|bysg==+4D77
TYTYATCYACTAYCTYATYCTAC
ACTYATCYATCYATCYATC
TPAPPAPPCAPPAPCPAC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take your existing code, and re-insert the leading `>` after the substitution:

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f
/^>/{
s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g
s/^/>/
}
```

Comment: is that supposed to be split across lines?

Comment: If you have GNU sed, you can combine the commands onto a single line by replacing linebreaks with `;`.  That's not specified in POSIX, and not all implementations support it.  You can use multiple sed statements on a command line if you really don't want to put your program in its own file - that would look like `sed -e '/^>/{' -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g' -e 's/^/>/' -e '}'`.   Personally, I find that soon gets hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

sed (Stream EDitor) is capable of performing the operation you specified, but a simpler tool might be more appropriate. If your system has sed, it probably has tr, as well. With tr you could do:

```
$ hdr=$(echo '>header 44554%782 & -GB' | tr -dc '>a-zA-Z0-9');
$ echo $hdr
>header44554782GB
```

The -c option tells tr to match the complement of the set of characters specified in '>a-zA-Z0-9', while the -d option tells tr to delete the matched characters.

Comment: that doesnt work exactly the way Id like it to. I have 1000s of headers, each with a sequence of letters below:                                                                           `>header$%hh2                                                                                                                               MPICUACAC                                                                                                               >header4@#B                                                                                                                  ATCYACYAC` and so on

Answer (score -1):

You do like this:

```
String result = yourString.replaceAll("[\\W&&[^<]]", "");
```

**Edited:**

```
var txt  = String(">header 44554%782 & -GB");
var exec = txt.replace(/[^>][\W]/g, "");
alert(exec);//>heade445578-GB
```

Comment: Id like to do it with sed. this pruning of the header is part of a pipe and needs to be done on millions of lines

Comment: I think you want to change the '^<' to '^>'.

Comment: This doesn't look like any kind of sed I've ever seen.

Comment: I am looking for a way to do this in sed. I need to go through millions of lines of text. The lines starting with ">" are just the headers or IDs for sequences. I guess I did not describe the data adequately. The text file I am working with has a header line (starting with ">") then multiple lines of letters, then a different header (starting with >) line, followed by multiple lines of letters, for 100,000 or so headers.

Comment: you can do it line by line, it is the fastest way,

Comment: @BahramdunAdil - which version of sed are you using? GNU sed says `unknown command: 'S'`...

Answer (score -1):

this may be simpler

```
sed -r '/^[>].*/{s/[^[:alnum:]_> ]//g}
```

example

```
echo '>header _44554%782? & -GB'|sed -r '/^[>].*/{s/[^[:alnum:]_> ]//g}'
```

ouptut

```
>header _44554782  GB
```

.

```
   > _ and space character protected
```